# How are ARM Registers referred to in binary

Tags: assembly, arm

I know ARM has a lot of registers and I was wondering what the mapping was between the register (r0 - r15, cpsr, etc) to their binary representation for being used in the final binary (basically what are the values that go into the Rn and Rd fields in the instruction).  For instance is it `r0` is `0b0000` and `r1` just `0b0001`? If so what is it when it comes to the specific CPU mode. Or does the CPU mode not affect the identifier of the register (I feel like it should be different codes).

Thanks.

Comment: If you have access to ARM instruction set details, you should refer to it. It should be quite simple.

Comment: @Why do you feel that it should differ?

Comment: I have 2 separate ARM manuals, and they refer to everything about the structure of the instructions (what bits are what and what they mean) but it doesn't have a mapping from register to it's binary relationship.

Comment: Well I figured it would differ since if you are in FIQ mode, then the CPSR before entering the mode is saved in SPSR_fiq and then is available again after leaving FIQ mode, or atleast how I understand it to be. I guess I have a LOT more reading to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get the ARM Architectural Reference Manual from infocenter.arm.com.  everything you want to know is right there.

The instructions encode r0 = 4'b0000 and r1 4'b0001, etc on up to r15 = 4'b1111.  there are some registers that are banked based on mode, supervisor mode, user mode interrupt mode, etc, the encoding in the instruction does not change r13 is a 13 in the encoding but somewhere in the processor is some flavor of if-then-else to get at the real register.  That is not visible to us that is buried in their logic.

The thumb instructions are generally limited to r0-r7 for most instructions, there are a few that are used specifically for moving to/from the higher numbered registers r8-r15, but the encoding is the same r0 = 0 r1 = 1, r2 = 2 and so on.

For many instruction sets you can figure this out on your own, try something like

```
add r0,r0,r1
add r0,r0,r2
add r0,r0,r3
add r0,r0,r4
...
add r0,r1,r0
add r0,r2,r0
add r0,r3,r0
...
```

and see what bits change after you assemble then disassemble...

Comment: Thanks, I will have to register at the ARM site then. I have been using things that didn't require registering.

Comment: If you want to do arm stuff, the architectural reference manual and the technical reference manual for the core you are working on is a must.  Note get the arm arm for armv5 to start if you dont have a specific one in mind, then get more of them as needed to see what has changed or been added over time.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.architecture.reference/index.html) is a link that will take you to the ARM webpage and allow you to download the ARM ARM.  The short answer is that it varies per architecture (V4-7), instruction, and instruction type (THUMB, ARM, THUMB2, 64-bit, etc.)

Comment: Does the actual value used within the bitfield to refer to a given register - say R5 - ever actually change?   The position of the bitfield for designating the register within the overall instruction word would clearly change (since the instruction word length changes), and the available registers and perhaps usage possibilities would change between variants.  But it would be very odd to see the registers suddenly numbered differently.  Perhaps with some of the extension registers though.

Comment: Yes between instruction sets and even not when the instruction requires a variable number registers to perform an operation (MUL vs MOV.)  As to the architecture changes  Thumb only supports 8 registers so its locations are different than ARM which supports 16.  They tend to stay fairly consistent across instructions, but not perfectly.

Comment: Ah, but you are correct in that the bit field location once it begins in an instruction, remains consistent unless it is a very specialized instruction.